# ¿Cómo puedo poner audio en mi web?

Tags: html, html5

Quiero poner una canción de fondo, pero no lo he logrado, estoy usando el siguiente código.

```
<bgsound src="solo.mp3" loop="-1">
```

Comment: Hola Jorge, yo siempre utilizo la etiqueta audio, en vez de bgsound, y me funciona bien.

Comment: Aquí https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/h/html-bgsound-tag.htm dice que `<bgsound>` sólo esta soportado en *internet explorer* y deberías usar el tag `<audio>`.

Comment: Pero hay una manera de poner el audio y que al abrir la página se reproduzca solo y con bucle?

Answer (score 0):

Cómo tal la especificación nos da una etiqueta HTML con nombre `audio` que entre varios atributos puede recibir el de `autoplay`.

Quedando de está forma

```
<audio src="yo.mp3" controls autoplay>
</audio>
```

Ahora sí quieres que una vez termine de reproducir la primera vez continúe entonces agrega el atributo `loop` además del que ya puse

Para .mayor referencia [leer aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Usando_audio_y_video_con_HTML5)

Comment: Hice uso de tu código pero no va la reproducción automática

Comment: Deberás consultar en la configuración de tu navegador, puede que la reproducción automática de multimedia este deshabilitada y por eso el audio no empieza pero te aseguro este que publiqué es el modo de hacerlo @JorgeGuadalupeGomezPimentel

Comment: Gracias, va ser eso lo seguro, ya lo activo

Answer (score 0):

Quiza el problema sea que no se inicia, ya que no le habias dado el comando para hacerlo. Si quieres, intenta probar con esto:

```
<audio src="solo.mp3" autoplay="true" loop="true"></audio>
```

Si quieres que el numero de veces que se repita el audio sea limitado, cambia el "true" dentro de loop al numero que tu quieras.